# how to export mysql server management then import into phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, .net

i have this mysql server management database written in .NET application. Now i want to export the database one table only then import into phpmyadmin. All i need to change is the header of the sql. Can someone help me figured this thing out?. TIA. Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: phpmyadmin is a web user interface that gives access to mysql databases. So if you have a mysql db already, then you could just install phpmyadmin on that server and log in with your db credentials.

Comment: I want to export windows mysql server management then import to phpmyadmin